# Update data record onBlur

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to update a record in a database onBlur but it does not work. Any ideas on how I can achieve this? my code looks like below.

**JS**

```
$(function () {
$("textarea").blur(function() {

       var meta_value =   $(this).val();
                var meta_key   =   $(this).attr("id");

             alert(meta_value + meta_key);


    $.get('script-url', { key: meta_Key, value: meta_value}, function(data) {

    });
});
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['key']))
{
   $meta_value = $_REQUEST['value'];
   $meta_key = $_REQUEST['key'];


$servername = "hhh";
$username = "hhh";
$password = "hhh";
$dbname = "hhh";


 global $wpdb;
 $user_ID = get_current_user_id();  



// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$sql = "UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = $meta_value WHERE meta_key = $meta_key AND user_id= $user_ID";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}


}
?>
```

Comment: Does alert() work on blur? And reformat your code. Its so messy

Comment: Add a simple alert in $.get to make sure AJAX is success

Comment: In PHP file, change POST to GET. Type `http://your_php_url?key=....&value=...` to see query work

Comment: @KmasterYC Nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

You are sending `key` & `value` to server not `meta_key`;

So update this condition

```
if(isset($_POST['meta_key'])){
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['key'])){
```

Comment: Ohh, really if this is not issue then what is the issue?

Comment: Try with the updated code and let us know what issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

issue? So really you never get results trying get POST values from a GET request
maybe use

```
$.on('ready', function() {
  $("textarea").on('blur', (function() {

    var meta_value = $(this).val();
    var meta_key = $(this).attr("id");

    alert(meta_value + meta_key);

    $.post('script-url', {
      key: meta_Key,
      value: meta_value
    }, function(data) {

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: use a *POST* method if you want use $_POST from PHP

Comment: I will try that and get back to you.